# How can I remove $ from imported html

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, currency, substitution, cryptoapi

I'm using the following code.

```
=(index(IMPORTHTML(concat("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/","bitcoin"),"table",1),1,2))
```

I would like to multiply with the number, however, I can't do that since it is treated as text.

Does any have any clue how I can remove the `$`?

Comment: your formula returns a numeric value. If you are seeing a $, it might just be the format

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet? Please remove any sensitive data if any. I have tried your formula and it works perfectly fine, it returns only the number without the dollar ($) sign. I am also able to multiply the result.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"&"bitcoin", 
 "table", 1), "[\$,]", )*1, 1, 2)
```

[image]